# AS3: error MethodInfo-26 and 25

Tags: actionscript-3, methodinfo

I made a game in AS3 and i have 2 as file. One is HWMain and HWGame. When i click start button the script is switch from HWMain to HWGame but i got this error.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
at HWGame()
at MethodInfo-26()
at MethodInfo-25()
```

Here's my code.

```
public class HWGame extends MovieClip
{
    var INIT_STATE:String = "INIT_STATE";
    var READY_STATE:String = "READY_STATE";
    var PLAYER_STATE:String = "PLAYER_STATE";
    var PLAY_STATE:String = "PLAY_STATE";
    var END_STATE:String = "END_STATE";
    var gameState:String;

    //And another variable

    public function HWGame()
    {
        gameState = INIT_STATE;
        trace(gameState);
        stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);

        function gameLoop(e:Event):void
        {
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case INIT_STATE :
                    initGame();
                    break;
                case READY_STATE :
                    ready();
                    break;
                case PLAYER_STATE :
                    startPlayer();
                    break;
                case PLAY_STATE :
                    playGame();
                    break;
                case END_STATE :
                    endGame();
                    break;
            }
        }

        function initGame():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        function ready():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        function startPlayer():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        function playGame():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        function endGame():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }
    }
}
```

I try to fixed it and i think the error is at gameState = INIT_STATE.
What should i do?

Thanks.

Comment: It's more likely that this `MovieClip` has not yet been added to the stage.  Therefore, `stage` is probably null at `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);`.

Comment: @JasonSturges, so.. i must delete stage code??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what you've cited, it's likely that your `HWGame` instance has not yet been added to the display list; therefore, `stage` is `null` when you call:

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
```

Before accessing `stage`, you could wait until added to stage:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class HWGame extends MovieClip
    {

        var INIT_STATE:String = "INIT_STATE";
        var READY_STATE:String = "READY_STATE";
        var PLAYER_STATE:String = "PLAYER_STATE";
        var PLAY_STATE:String = "PLAY_STATE";
        var END_STATE:String = "END_STATE";
        var gameState:String;

        public function HWGame()
        {
            gameState = INIT_STATE;

            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);
        }

        protected function addedToStageHandler(event:Event):void
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedToStageHandler);

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
        }

        protected function gameLoop(e:Event):void
        {
            switch (gameState)
            {
                case INIT_STATE:
                    initGame();
                    break;
                case READY_STATE:
                    ready();
                    break;
                case PLAYER_STATE:
                    startPlayer();
                    break;
                case PLAY_STATE:
                    playGame();
                    break;
                case END_STATE:
                    endGame();
                    break;
            }
        }

        protected function initGame():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        protected function ready():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        protected function startPlayer():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        protected function playGame():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }

        protected function endGame():void
        {
            //I write the long code
        }
    }
}
```